# symfony 2 cannot find the route i've created

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a route named "test" but symfony cannot find it.

Routing_dev.php

```
_test:
   resource: "@AcmetestBundle/Controller/testController.php"
   type:     annotation
   pattern:  /test
```

Added this line to AppKernel.php

```
$bundles[] = new Acme\testBundle\AcmetestBundle();
```

Created a dir described below

1. Acme |
    1.1   testBundle
             |
             1.11    AcmetestBundle.php
             |
             1.12    Controller
                      |
                      1.13       testController.php

AcmetestBundle.php

```
namespace Acme\testBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
class AcmetestBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function __construct(){
        var_dump("initializing ".__DIR__);
    }
}
```

testController.php

```
namespace Acme\testBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\ContactType;
// these import the "@Route" and "@Template" annotations
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
class testController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="_demo")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {     var_dump(11);
        return array("");
    }
}
```

Browser logs :

> No route found for "GET /test" 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException 1
>   linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
>
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route
>   found for "GET /test" (uncaught exception) at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 4560

Comment: what does `php app/console route:dump` say?

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to write **prefix** instead of pattern:

```
_test:
   resource: "@AcmetestBundle/Controller/testController.php"
   type:     annotation
   prefix:  /test
```

Comment: ok thanks it worked but what's wrong with pattern ? I google but could n't understand the diff

Comment: `resource` says that you want to import patterns from an external resource. `prefix` is just a prefix for the imported patterns.